I'm doing cs50 finance problem and i have an error with the buy function
Here is the code :
@app.route("/buy", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def buy():
    """Buy shares of stock"""
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("buy.html")

    else:
        symbol = request.form.get("symbol")
        shares = request.form.get("shares")
        if not symbol:
            return apology("must give symbol", 403)
        quote = lookup(symbol)
        if quote == None:
            return apology("symbol dose not exist", 403)
        if not shares:
            return apology("must give number of shares", 403)
        if int(shares) < 0:
            return apology("share must be positive", 403)
        cost = int(shares) * quote["price"]
        user_id = session["user_id"]
        cash = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = :user_id", user_id=user_id)
        user_cash = cash[0]["cash"]
        if user_cash < cost:
            return  apology("you dont have enough mony")
        new_cash = user_cash - cost
        db.execute("update users set cash= ? WHERE id = ?",new_cash, user_id)

        db.execute("INSERT INTO transactions (user_id, symbol, shares, price) values(:user_id, :symbol, :shares, :price)",user_id = session["user_id"], symbol=symbol, shares=shares, price=quote["price"])

        flash("Bought!")

        return redirect("/")


And here's the error :
INFO: SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = 1
INFO: update users set cash= 9663.759999999995 WHERE id = 1
ERROR: INSERT INTO transactions (user_id, symbol, shares, price) values(1, 't', '1', 18.68)
ERROR: Exception on /buy [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1473, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 882, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 880, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 865, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/workspaces/111413212/finance/helpers.py", line 48, in decorated_function
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/workspaces/111413212/finance/app.py", line 94, in buy
    db.execute("INSERT INTO transactions (user_id, symbol, shares, price) values(:user_id, :symbol, :shares, :price)",user_id = session["user_id"], symbol=symbol, shares=shares, price=quote["price"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/cs50/sql.py", line 28, in decorator
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/cs50/sql.py", line 473, in execute
    raise e
RuntimeError: no such table: main.user
INFO: 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jul/2024 16:00:49] "POST /buy HTTP/1.1" 500 

The problem is in the insert to the table transaction but i dont know what it is
i try to remove it then the code work with out any error
and in the terminal the sentince insert into table ... is in red
and i tryed to do it a different way :
db.execute("INSERT INTO transactions (user_id, symbol, shares, price) values(?, ?, ?, ?)",user_id , quote["symbol"], shares, quote["price"])

and it gave me the same error

i made a new table and did the same thing and it worked
but still dont know what is the problem in this table

The error message doesn't match the code you posted. The error message says FROM user, but the code says FROM users. It seems that FROM users is correct, because the error message says there's no table named user.

So I suspect you got this error from an earlier version of the code, and you've now fixed the typo.
